# JSF 2 and the Basic HTTP authentication

Tags: jsf-2, basic-authentication

We have an web app what uses Basic HTTP authentication.

web.xml

```
...
<login-config>
    <auth-method>BASIC</auth-method>
    <realm-name>file</realm-name>
</login-config>
...
```

Indirect usage somewhere in the deep code space ...

```
User getLogedUser(HttpServletRequest request)
```

And I have to rewrite it in JSF 2, but I have no clue how can use the this authentication method in JSF 2. (i could not find the way how can i get 'HttpServletRequest request')

Google did not throw any useful hit on his first page

Thanks for the answers in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The raw `HttpServletRequest` is in JSF available by [`ExternalContext#getRequest()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRequest%28%29).

```
ExternalContext ec = FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext();
HttpServletRequest request = (HttpServletRequest) ec.getRequest();
// ...
```

However, I think it's better to change the `getLoggedUser()` method to take the remote user instead.

```
User getLoggedUser(String remoteUser)
```

so that you can just feed either [`ExternalContext#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29) or [`HttpServletRequest#getRemoteUser()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/servlet/http/HttpServletRequest.html#getRemoteUser%28%29) to it. This also decouples the method from any Servlet API or JSF API dependency.

Answer (score 1):

I guess you are looking for [ExternalContext.getRemoteUser()](http://docs.oracle.com/javaee/6/api/javax/faces/context/ExternalContext.html#getRemoteUser%28%29)
which returns the user name.

Usage:

```
FacesContext.getCurrentInstance().getExternalContext().getRemoteUser();
```